# Install and configuring pg_cron extension with PostgreSQL 14 on macOS Sonoma

Tags: postgresql, macos-sonoma, pg-cron

I'm currently facing an issue while trying to install the pg_cron extension with PostgreSQL on macOS. I've followed the steps outlined in the documentation and various online resources, but I'm encountering difficulties getting it to work properly.

Description of the Issue:

- I have PostgreSQL 14.11 installed on my macOS system.
- I've downloaded and compiled pg_cron version 1.4.1 from the GitHub repository.
- I've configured pg_cron in the postgresql.conf file by adding shared_preload_libraries = 'timescaledb, pg_cron' (I already have timescaledb and want to adding pg_cron
  However, upon starting PostgreSQL, I'm encountering errors related to loading the pg_cron library.

[image: Error could not start server]

Step i tried:

1. Cloned the pg_cron repository from GitHub. --> https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron
2. Checked out the v1.4.1 release.
3. Compiled pg_cron using make. Then i got error from make and fixed it by remove -Werror in Makefile of pg_cron
4. Added pg_cron to the shared_preload_libraries parameter in postgresql.conf
5. Restarted PostgreSQL. (got error could not start server)

Question:
Can anyone provide guidance on how to correctly configure pg_cron with PostgreSQL on macOS? Are there any additional steps or configurations I might be missing? How can I troubleshoot the error preventing the PostgreSQL server from starting after adding pg_cron to shared_preload_libraries?

Comment: As always when there are trouble starting PostgreSQL: 1) look into the PostgreSQL server log 2) Try to start the server by hand using `postgres` or `pg_ctl` and look at the error messages you get. Then you should know more about the problem, which will bring you vloser to a solution.